# `git push heroku master` fails because it is using the wrong email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I created a rails app with

```
$ rails new appname
$ cd appname
```

I initialized it as a git repo

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'init'
```

I logged into heroku

```
$ heroku login
Email: correct@email.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
```

I created the heroku app

```
$ heroku create
Creating radiant-bayou-6540... done, stack is cedar
http://radiant-bayou-6540.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:radiant-bayou-6540.git
Git remote heroku added
```

I tried to push to heroku

```
$ git push heroku master
!  Your account incorrect@email.com does not have access to radiant-bayou-6540.
```

Wait what? I didn't log in with incorrect@email.com, I logged in with correct@email.com. Let's look at git

```
$ git config user.email
correct@email.com
```

What?! Why does heroku think I'm logging in with wrong@email.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Source](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/account-does-not-have-access-to-app-on-git-push/125)

Your account SSH keys is tied to your old email.  You are going to have to transfer it over to  your new account

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: incorrect@email.com
Password: 

$ heroku keys:remove incorrect@email.com
```

and add it to your new account

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: correct@email.com
Password: 

$ heroku keys:add
```

Failing that, try recreating and add a new ssh key

Comment: Afterward, I ran into another problem, which turned out to be that I needed to `ssh-add ~/.ssh/my-new-key`, but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Removing known_hosts entry for ssh should help.
For linux and mac it is in the $HOME/.ssh directory

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I simply had to switch to using ssh.

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadOf https://git.heroku.com/
```

If the heroku remote uses `https`, git seems to pull the credentials from elsewhere.